# Japanese Characters display weird spacing in Android TextView and Buttons

Tags: android, utf-8, internationalization

I'm trying to localize an android app to Japanese.  I dropped in the japanese strings xml file and everything is pretty good except for Katakana characters with the two little dashes or the little circle in the top right.  For those characters the display takes up the width of 2 full characters.

Here's a simple example showing the spacing problem with the word "website" in katakana:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="ウェブサイト"       
        android:typeface="normal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When it displays on the phone, the 3rd character takes up an extra space.  Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change the character "ブ" -> "ブ".
The 3rd character is not used ordinary Japanese in UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah, it seems some of the characters were not proper UTF-8 - I had the translator re-send the bad strings and now everything is looking good.

Comment: What is different between the two character "ブ" -> "ブ"?

Comment: First "ブ" is (%E3%83%95%E3%82%99). Actually it is included combined character (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) and not recommended. Second "ブ" is (%E3%83%96). UTF-8 Japanese usually use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try externalizing the string into strings.xml. Doing that I don't have this problem.

Comment: the string is already externalized - I just put it in the layout to make the example code simple.  Are you using a special font or anything?

Comment: No. What is your encoding? UTF-8? What operating system? Mine works on Linux and Mac..